# swf loaded into QtWebKit

Tags: flash, amf, qtwebkit

I need to load a swf into QWebKit and i need that swf to connect to my Amf server but it seems that something blocks the swf from connection and/or calling any function on the server. If i load the swf into any external browser(Chrom, Firefix, IE, Safari) it runs without problems.

Anyone ever had this issue ? or can anyone give me any hint on what is going on ?

NOTE: The swf is loaded locally (file:///path)

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to enable plug-in support in `QWebSettings`? This should do the trick:

```
QWebSettings::globalSettings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
```

Comment: Yes, i enabled the plugins. I also enabled QWebSettings::LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls and QWebSettings::LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls.

Comment: EDIT: After playing around with my swf and the QtWebKit i noticed that the NetConnection is closed after each call to the Amf server.